# Use osascript script to open terminal and run npm command

Tags: macos, unix, npm

i don't much of max unix command.

What I want to do is open two different terminals and run npm in each one of them.

```
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."

osascript -e  'npm run build'

sleep 3

echo "Starting firebase functions...."

osascript -e 'firebase emulators:start --only functions'

echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

This is what i wrote and this is what I am getting in terminal

```
Starting typescript build in new terminal..
8:13: syntax error: Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found identifier. (-2741)
Starting firebase functions....
0:18: syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open
```

Can somone help me out in correcting my shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd && npm run build"' &
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd && firebase emulators:start --only functions"' &
```

Comment: Can you please answer a relative question to this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658602/shell-script-relative-position-from-the-file