# shell script relative position from the file

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, command-line-interface

I have almost no idea about shell scripts or commands in linux

I have a project named `projectx`

`projectX` happens to be in `users/hardik/desktop/projectx`

I have created a shell script `start.sh`. This is the content of shell script

```
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run build"' 

sleep 3

echo "Starting firebase functions...."

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "firebase emulators:start --only functions"'


echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

now this works but say here

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run build"'`

it runs that in the root and hence gives the following error

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `/Users/hardik/package.json`

How can I make it execute in the path which is relative to `start.sh`

Update: I tried this

```
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."
path=`pwd`
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd ${path} npm run watch:scss"' 
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run watch"'

echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

but this didn't work with error `cd: too many arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Just change directory to where you need to be prior to running `npm`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /Users/somewhere && npm run build"'
```

Comment: Path can be different for different users cloning the repo. they all would b running it on mac that's for sure. I have updated the question as well

Comment: You appear to have missed the `&&` between `cd somewhere` and `npm run build` ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the line:

```
cd `dirname $0`
```

at the top of start.sh. The dirname command produces the directory that a file contains, and $0 is the path that invoked start.sh, so that's the relative directory that you wanted. Note those quotes a left-quotes, so the result of running dirname is passed to cd.